# Calling a function with a floating number

Tags: python, function, user-interface, tkinter, floating-point

Hi I'm trying to solve this problem. I keep getting an error message saying

> can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

I'm using the tkinter module aswell.

```
list=[]
print amount.get()     #Using the Tkinter Spinbox widget, .get()
                       #retrieves the amount/input in that widget
if amount.get() > 0:
    list.append(amount.get())
    amount = 0
    for a in list:             #Makes the number in a list a float no. 
        for b in a.split():
            try:
                amount += float(b)
            except:
                pass
    print amount
    function_one() * amount  #I'm trying to call the function 
                             #definition with the amount but I get the 
                             #error message         
    del list[0] #delete the amount for the user to input a different 
                #number
```

Which I'm trying to call the function with the "amount" of times (number "amount" from the "if-statement":

```
def function_one():
   print "Select"
```

There is a lot more variables etc in the definition above. You don't have to create the tkinter widgets etc but a solution to fixing how to call the function with the amount of times would be great!

If you are still confused, I am very sorry, for example, if i had the amount = 5, I want the function to be called 5 times.

Please and thank you :)

Comment: is it even possible as per your syntax? Use loop

Comment: Probably a different way to solve this. maybe a "for each" loop?

Comment: What exactly you want to do? let amount is 5.5, call function 5.5 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you not use a for loop, i.e:

```
for i in range(int(amount.get())): 
    function_one()
```

Comment: Short and made it simple. I made my code too long and complicating. Thank you! It works